# SwiftUI using .NavigationDestination is making the app go back on the view after pressing the button

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

After changing the code to use NavigationStack and list to list clickable items which open a different View. Clicking the item changes the view for a second and then bounces back to HomeView.

## **HomeView.swift**

`

```
//
//  HomeView.swift
//  LDMT
//
//  Created by Aniruddha Pandit on 2022/9/18.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm = SearchVar()
    @EnvironmentObject private var AuthModel: AuthViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @State var signOutProcessing = false
    @State private var query = ""
    private var cases : [Case] = Case.allCase
    
    
    func signOutUser() {
        signOutProcessing = true
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
            signOutProcessing = false
        }
        withAnimation {
            viewRouter.currentPage = .signInPage
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(cases) { Cases in
                        NavigationLink(Cases.cnrNumber, value: Cases)
                    }
                    .padding(12)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Case.self) { cases in
                    DetailView(cases: cases)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        if signOutProcessing {
                            ProgressView()
                        } else {
                            Button("Sign Out") {
                                signOutUser()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Case List")
            }
            .searchable(text: $query, placement: .automatic, prompt: "Search by Case...") {
                
            }
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                vm.search(with: query)
                print(type(of: vm.filteredData))
            }
            .onAppear {
                vm.search()
            }
        } else {
            // add a fall back for NavigationStack
        }
    }
}
    
    
    struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
```

`

## **DetailView**

```
//
//  DetailView.swift
//  LDMT
//
//  Created by Aniruddha Pandit on 2022/10/5.
//

import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    var cases : Case
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    func myExibit() {
        withAnimation {
            viewRouter.currentPage = .evidencePage
        }
    }
    
    func myCases() {
        withAnimation {
            viewRouter.currentPage = .homePage
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    Text("CNR Number : \(cases.cnrNumber)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Petition And Advocate : \(cases.petitionerAndAdvocate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Respondant And Advocate : \(cases.respondantAndAdvocate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Court : \(cases.court)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Registration Date : \(cases.registrationDate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Registration Number : \(cases.registrationNumber)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Filing Date : \(cases.filingDate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Filing Number : \(cases.filingNumber)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("First Hearing Date : \(cases.firstHearingDate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text("Next Hearing Date : \(cases.nextHearingDate)")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("My Evidence") {
                            myExibit()
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button("My Cases") {
                            myCases()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(cases: Case.sampleCase)
    }
}
```

Am I using the .navigationDestination wrong? my end goal is to just change view on tap. Sorry if this is already answered I'm new to swift and still learning.

I have tried to follow the app developer documentation but for .navigationDestination there isn't a lot.

Comment: you probably should not use another `NavigationStack` in `DetailView`, try removing it.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue.

I fixed it by removing the `NavigationStack {}` from the `Details View`, and it worked straight away.